# Why didn't Russia and Japan sign a peace treaty after WW2?

Tags: world-war-two, soviet-union, japan, international-relations

I have read that Russia and Japan, which had been fighting long before World War I, are still at war, at least technically, since they did not sign a peace treaty at the conclusion of World War II.

So, the question is, why have Russia and Japan not signed a peace treaty?

Comment: Where did you read that?  Citations are very useful in unraveling historical puzzles

Answer (score 22):

The reason is an unresolved territorial dispute over four islets, annexed by the Red Army during the [Manchurian Strategic Offensive Operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manchurian_Strategic_Offensive_Operation). In Russia the dispute is known as the [Kuril Islands dispute](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuril_Islands_dispute), and in Japan as the Northern Territories dispute.

Russian President Vladimir Putin and Japanese Prime Minister Shinzo Abe have recently restarted negotiations to end the dispute:

> The two leaders agreed it was "abnormal" their countries had not signed a peace treaty 67 years after the end of World War II, according to a joint declaration adopted in the Kremlin on Monday.
>
> They expressed determination to overcome "the existing differences" on the islands dispute through talks, the declaration said.
>
> "We have instructed our foreign ministries to step up contacts on working out mutually acceptable options" for an end to the dispute, Putin said after talks with Abe.
>
> <sub>Source: [Russia and Japan vow to solve islands dispute](http://www.aljazeera.com/video/asia/2013/04/20134295949969791.html), Al Jazeera</sub>

Further reading:

- [Russia, Japan renew quest for elusive WWII peace treaty](http://articles.latimes.com/2013/may/01/world/la-fg-wn-russia-japan-peace-treaty-20130430), Los Angeles Times.
- [Kuril islands dispute between Russia and Japan](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-asia-pacific-11664434), BBC

Comment: Yannis, then, why have I got another downvote?

Comment: @Carlo_R. If you hover over the downvote arrow, a tooltip will appear. It says: "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful (click again to undo)". Your question does not show any research effort, I guess that's what the downvote is for.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a short text to read: [San Francisco Treaty etc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treaty_of_San_Francisco#Soviet_Union's_opposition_to_the_Treaty)

Soviet (Russian) position since then was, at first, a general objection to Japan being used as a base for US operations in the region; and then an impossibility to resolve the Kuril Islands issue. Nowadays it seems next to impossible to resolve, seeing as how both countries cannot afford to lose face.